# I want to sort data, and exclude results before todays date, it works on it's own, but not with the rest of my query

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the problem. I'm searching cruises, based on a search field entry. I only want to return cruises that haven't sailed yet. I'm searching title, destination, code in the cruises table and ports in the itinerary table. I search at the moment, and get cruises that are in the past ?

```
$query_search_cruises = sprintf("SELECT id, title, code FROM cruises WHERE departs >   CURDATE() AND title LIKE %s OR destination LIKE %s OR code LIKE %s OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM itinerary WHERE port LIKE %s AND cruises.id = cruise_id )", GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_search . "%", "text"), GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_search . "%", "text"), GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_search . "%", "text"), GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_search . "%", "text"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, `AND` has [a higher precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) than `OR` so your query is effectively:

```
WHERE (departs > CURDATE() AND title LIKE %s) OR (destination LIKE %s) OR ...
```

and `(destination LIKE %s)` will get all rows matching that condition *regardless of the* `departs` *column.*

If you want different precedence you will have to group the terms *explicitly,* such as with:

```
WHERE departs > CURDATE() AND (title LIKE %s OR destination LIKE %s OR ... )
```